# Single React element child error - wrap statements inside a root component?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm seeing the error below with the second setState for the group.

> Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

From reading it looks like I need to wrap these statements inside a root component or something similar; anyone help?

```
async componentDidMount() {
if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
  return;
}

try {
  const notes = await this.notes();
  this.setState({ notes });

  const group = await this.group();
  this.setState({ group });
} catch (e) {
  alert(e);
}
```

The full file can be found here - github.com/dodo83/giftlist/blob/master/Home.js

Comment: Hi Chris, while I have been out of the React community for a while, it isn't immediately obvious to me how your error message matches the code you posted. It may be easier for others to help you if you can reproduce the problem in an online code sharing tool such as https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codepen.io/

Comment: What does your `render()` method look lilke?

Comment: github.com/dodo83/giftlist/blob/master/Home.js is the full file, cheers

Answer (score 0):

you need to return `null`, `<></>` or some kind of React component, e.g. `<div>Foo</div>`

Need to see your `render` function

I would also suggest you group the `setState` calls to a single call, e.g. 
`this.setState({ notes, group});` once the promises have resolved

Personally, i'd simplify your code to something more along these lines:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return;
    }

    try {

      const notes = await API.get("notes", "/notes");
      const group = await API.get("group", "/group");
      this.setState({ group , notes, isLoading: false});

    } catch (e) {

    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/dodo83/giftlist/blob/master/Home.js is the full file, cheers

Comment: hmm, that file is rather long, there seem to be some parts missing from the state, e.g. `isGroupLoading`, `isNotesLoading`

Comment: My bad, wrong version.  Those 2 states should just be isLoading - I've updated the file in GitHub

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked out what the issue was.  I'd left a

```
*/}
```

in the middle of the renderGroup() method which is called by render() - (line 86)